# width of the TextField decrease in Xamarin(iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, textfield

I am new in Xamarin and iOS. I want to add Constraint in the `TextField` so that `TextField` display in the all Screen good. But whenever I add Constraint the red cut line is display and it will decrease my `TextField` width. I you can see in the below picture. What is that red cutted rectangle and how to set my `TextField` to `width` to my `Label` width. Forgive if this is silly mistake and not big issue.

[image]

I am new to iOS world. Any help be Appreciated.

**Update :**

my `Text Field` Constraint

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good thing that you want to bring your Android's way to manage the layout of iOS view.

Most of the iOS developers like using "Frame" property, like:

```
UILabel lbTitle = new UILabel();
lbTitle.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 100, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 30);
```

Then it will always full of your screen.

Of cause you can use "NSLayoutConstraint", but believe me there are few people use it, and if you get some problem with it, it's more harder to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry but i forget to post answer. But yes, `Constraint` is work for me. So I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

iOS need X and Y coordinator to determine position of the View (in this case is the Label).
On your picture, I saw you only create top constraint of your label to "First Name", it defines Y constraint. You have to create X constraint to make it works. By default X will be 0 if you don't define it

Comment: I know that but When I set `X` and `Y` Constraint then also it's width is decrease. as you can see it's width is set to `red cutted rectangle`.

Comment: @Ironman can you capture Right Panel of your IDE, Tab Properties -> Layout

Comment: Ya Sure.. Wait a mintue... I will update my question.